# jQuery Scrolling Div Heights

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple div header (illustrated in code below) when I scroll down I don't wish for the window itself to scroll but make the div height decrease.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="javascripts/headani.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="pageTop"></div>
        <div id="pageArticle">
            <div class="siteDesc">
                <p id="hello"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS is:

```
body {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    background-color: beige;
}
#pageTop {
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: tan;
}
#pageArticle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
#siteDesc {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: black;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

And finally my jQuery is: (keep in mind this is just a rough model and some testing vars may still be in there so if vars are not used or a function is not used how it is intended then may I apologize for not doing some house keeping)

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var headHeight = $('#pageTop').height();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if (headHeight > 50) {
            $(document).bind("scroll", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault;
            })
            headHeight = (headHeight - 1);
            $('#pageTop').css('height', headHeight);
        }
        $('#hello').html($(document).scrollTop() + "<br/>" + headHeight);
    })
});
```

I got it to work to minimize the div on a scroll both up and down (which I will accomplish to make smaller on scroll down and larger on scroll up) but the problem I have is I do not want to body to scroll until pageTop's height is 50! I am just wondering what is the best way to accomplish this? As you can see I tried to bind scrolling but that failed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the scroll event fires straight after the scrolling ocurred, so you can't prevent the event default action because the action already happened (it scrolled). So what you can do is listen up for the `wheel` event and `keydown` event to stop the action.

```js
$.fn.scrollEvent = function(handler) {
  this.on('wheel', function(e) {
    handler(e);
  });
  this.on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 40) {
      handler(e);
    }
  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  var headHeight = $('#pageTop').height();
  window.scrollEvent
  $(window).scrollEvent(function(e) {
    if (headHeight > 50) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      headHeight = (headHeight - 30);
      $('#pageTop').css('height', headHeight);
    }
    $('#hello').html($(document).scrollTop() + "<br/>" + headHeight);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  background-color: beige;
}
#pageTop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: tan;
}
#pageArticle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
#siteDesc {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/headani.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="pageTop"></div>
  <div id="pageArticle">
    <div class="siteDesc">
      <p id="hello"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I made a fix for it, it's very ugly but it also disables scroll down by pressing the down arrow.